Pure virtual method called in derived class Player
I've been writing a simple 2D game in SFML. I've done a draft version of the game, but when I run the program, it reports an error:

Pure virtual method called

The debugger wrote the problem is in the GameObject->Update() method. Precisely, in Player->Update(). As you see, I've written an abstract class GameObject to use subclasses in the main() function properly.
GameObject.h
#include <memory>
#include "Window.h"

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject() = default;
    virtual void Update(const float& frametime) = 0;
    virtual void Render(const std::shared_ptr<Window>& window) = 0;
    virtual sf::Vector2f getPosition() = 0;
    virtual ~GameObject() = default;
};

Player.h
#include "Graphics.hpp"
#include"Audio.hpp"
#include "Window.h"
#include "ObjectConstructor.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

using namespace std::chrono;

class Player : public GameObject {
public:
    Player();
    void Update(const float& frametime) override;
    void Render(const std::shared_ptr<Window>& window) override;
    sf::Vector2f getPosition() override;
    ~Player() override;

    void SetOC(ObjectConstructor* oc);

private:
    float speed = 125; //default speed
    ObjectConstructor* OC = nullptr; //Object constructor to get game data
    sf::Vector2f m_pos;
    sf::Texture m_playerTexture;
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    sf::Sound ShotSound;
    steady_clock::time_point lastShotTime;
    duration<float> timeBetweenShots = 0.45s;

};

Player. cpp
#include "../include/Player.h"
#include "../include/Bullet.h"

Player::Player()
{
    m_playerTexture.loadFromFile("../assets/ship.png");
    m_pos = sf::Vector2f(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width / 8, sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height / 2);
    lastShotTime = steady_clock::now();
    buffer.loadFromFile("../assets/shootSFX.mp3");
    ShotSound.setBuffer(buffer);
}

void Player::Update(const float& frametime)
{
    sf::Event event;
    sf::RenderWindow& m_window = OC->GetWindow()->GetRenderWindow();
    while(m_window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W && m_pos.y > 64)
                m_pos.y += speed * frametime;
            else if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S && m_pos.y < m_window.getSize().y -64)
                m_pos.y -= speed * frametime;

            if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space && lastShotTime + timeBetweenShots <= steady_clock::now()){
                //some shooting logic
                Bullet newBullet(m_pos,OC->GetWindow());
                newBullet.SetOC(OC);
                OC->GetObjects()->push_back(&newBullet);

                ShotSound.play();
                lastShotTime = steady_clock::now();
            }
        }
    }
}

void Player::Render(const std::shared_ptr<Window>& window)
{
    sf::RenderWindow& m_window = OC->GetWindow()->GetRenderWindow();
    sf::Sprite sprite(m_playerTexture, sf::IntRect(m_pos.x - m_playerTexture.getSize().x /2,
        m_pos.y - m_playerTexture.getSize().y /2,m_playerTexture.getSize().x,m_playerTexture.getSize().y));
    m_window.draw(sprite);
}

void Player::SetOC(ObjectConstructor* oc){
    OC = oc;
}

sf::Vector2f Player::getPosition()
{
    return m_pos;
}

ObjectConstructor.h
class Player;
class Bullet;

class ObjectConstructor {
public:
    ObjectConstructor();
    ~ObjectConstructor() = default;
    std::shared_ptr<Window> GetWindow();
    std::vector<GameObject*>* GetObjects();
    std::vector<Bullet*>* GetBullets();
    // std::vector<Enemy*>* GetEnemies();
private:
    int score = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Window> m_window;
    std::vector<GameObject*> m_game_objects;
    std::vector<Bullet*> bulletCollisionObjects;
};

ObjectConstructor.cpp
ObjectConstructor::ObjectConstructor()
{
    Window temp_w = Window("Space Wars", sf::Vector2u(720, 1280));
    m_window = std::move(std::make_shared<Window>(temp_w));
    Player newPlayer = Player();
    newPlayer.SetOC(this);
    m_game_objects.push_back(std::move(&newPlayer));
}

std::vector<GameObject*>* ObjectConstructor::GetObjects(){
    return &m_game_objects;
}

std::shared_ptr<Window> ObjectConstructor::GetWindow()
{
    return m_window;
}

std::vector<Bullet*>* ObjectConstructor::GetBullets(){
    return &bulletCollisionObjects;
}

main.cpp
#include "../RegularGame/include/Player.h"
#include "../RegularGame/include/Bullet.h"
#include "../RegularGame/include/ObjectConstructor.h"
#include "../RegularGame/include/Game.h"

int main()
{
    ObjectConstructor objects;
    while (objects.GetWindow().get()->IsDone() == 0)
    {
        for (auto& gameObject : *objects.GetObjects())
        {
            gameObject->Update(0.015);
            objects.GetWindow().get()->Update();
        }
        for (auto& gameObject : *objects.GetObjects())
        {
            gameObject->Render(objects.GetWindow());
        }
    }
    objects.~ObjectConstructor();
    return 0;
}


"As you see I've wrode abstract class GameObject to use subclasses in main function properly" - Since it doesn't work you obviously didn't do it correctly.

*objects.GetObjects() look suspicious to me.

objects.~ObjectConstructor(); is simply wrong. destructor is called at end of scope.

The problem is in ObjectConstructor, which you did not show.

As you see I've wrode abstract class GameObject to use subclasses in main function properly -- Never say this if you have an issue with the running of the code.  By saying this, you are admitting to yourself that your code is bug-free, and the reason why things are not working is that it has something to do with the "system", compiler, etc.

Bullet newBullet(m_pos,OC->GetWindow()); OC->GetObjects()->push_back(&newBullet); is wrong too, you store address of local variable, so dangling pointer once scope ends.

I added ObjectConstructor class code, I think there's a problem with links logic

@Eralife7 The problem with ObjectConstructor is the same problem already pointed out by Jarod42.  You are storing the address of a temporary.

Should I use std::move or make m_game_objects field std::vector type?

I would first get rid of the excessive usage of raw pointers.  Why not use references?   Why not return references instead of raw pointers?   Why not a vector of smart pointers instead of vectors of raw pointers, i.e. std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> instead of std::vector<GameObject*>?

Read about the new operator and what it does, then forget all about it and go use shared_ptr and unique_ptr as others have said.

auto newPlayer = std::make_unique<Player>(); newPlayer->SetOC(this); m_game_objects.push_back(std::move(newPlayer)); -- This is probably what you really wanted to do, but that means that your vector should be of unique_ptr, not raw pointers.  I don't know if this change (and also change in the other places you are doing this) gets rid of the error, but definitely your current code is obviously broken due to storing the address of temporaries.

There are far too many pointers here. Having a pointer to a vector is particularly wrong. It's a common beginner mistake. Remove all the pointers you do not need (which is most I think) and the one's you do should be smart pointers.

Thanks to you all, now I am rewriting most part of my code. I understand that methods mere right, but pointers usage is absolutely wrong

The post is too long. But I guess a nullptr exception is hiding in the corner. C++ doesn't allow instantiation of abstract classes - unless as a sub-objects of concrete derived classes. So pure function call at runtime only means invalid pointer use; the later can happen for many reasons, but I want to put my money on nullptr now.
